# How can I get Notepad to show white margins on the top and sides, like in Windows Vista/7?

Tags: windows-10, notepad, margins

I recently got a Windows 10 computer that I've been customizing to visually resemble my previously-owned Windows Vista & 7 computers.  I'm making great progress towards finalizing my customization, but I've hit a bit of a roadblock.

I want Notepad to show those little white margins at the top & sides of the program window, like it used to do on Windows Vista & Windows 7. See [here](https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/81968-notepad-margins-0-after-creators-update.html):

- No margin

  [image: Notepad without margin]
- With margin

  [image: Notepad with margin]

The problem is, I've tried numerous searches on Google about dealing with this issue, only to hardly get any results!

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: `Surely, there must be something that can be done to get those margins back` why are you so sure? And which margin are you talking about? I've never seen any margin in Notepad

Comment: 1. Well, I'm sure because I've discovered a LOT of fascinating new tweaks, tricks, & tips to customize my computer however I'd like. :-) I've learned to do stuff I never even thought possible before! / 2. Oh, I forgot to add pictures!  Silly me! https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/software-apps/130231d1492262268t-notepad-margins-0-after-creators-update-notepad_with-margin.png

Comment: And here's a picture of what the margins in Notepad look like now: https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/software-apps/130169d1492226296t-notepad-margins-0-after-creators-update-notepad_no-margin.png

Comment: @davidbaumann Yes...but do you know of any such software--or registry tweaks, or anything else--that can add those Vista-style white margins in Notepad? :-( Having no margins is driving me crazy!

Comment: @davidbaumann Also, what is "back color"?

Comment: @phuclv Now that I've shown you a picture of the margins I'm talking about, can you (or someone you know) possibly help me? :-)

Comment: Drat it, isn't there anyone who can possibly help me out? :-(

Comment: I've always been on the fast insider ring and I don't think I've never seen Notepad with such a narrow margin. Probably because I don't use Notepad much but currently I'm using the latest 19H1 and the appearance is still properly with margins

Comment: @phuclv I'm not sure what my build is...but I still wonder if there's a registry tweak, or third-party software, or another way to make the margins look normal.

Comment: @phuclv Do you still have any other ideas?

Comment: I updated to Windows 11 today and have the opposite problem: there is too much of a margin in Notepad. @TheMouseAvenger did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Click on **File>Page Setup**
On the Margins section, set your margins of the right side as well as the top as required!

Comment: I'm afraid that only works for printing out Notepad files, not fixing the actual appearance of Notepad in Windows. :-( Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: I too see this, when I find a positive answer, I will update you accordingly.

Comment: Have you figured out that "positive answer" yet? :-)